# SQL tool to run an select query against multiple Informix servers?

Tags: sql, database, informix

I was using SQL Explorer to connect to an Informix server and get the output. Now I wish to run the same select query on multiple servers and get the results in each server. Could someone tell how its done with SQL explorer or if there is any other tool that will get the work done? Steps to do will be much appreciated.

Comment: There are several possibilities.  You could continue working with the connection to your current Informix server, and rephrase the query to use `FROM dbname@server02:yourtable` or equivalent (prefix the table name(s)) with the database name (`dbname`) and server name (`server02`) and run the 'distributed' (remote) query.  Or you can arrange to connect to each database in turn and run the query.  Being low-tech and Unix-based, I'd probably create a shell script that connected to each server in turn and ran the appropriate query and captured the result.

Comment: thanks for the response but this does not help.